# Por que muitas pessoas respondem nos comentários em vez de criar uma resposta?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comentários, comunidade, perguntas-sem-resposta

Eu não entendo. Vejo vários comentários que solucionam a questão. Mas ficam como comentários e não como resposta da questão. Isso não pode atrapalhar? Pois quando vou na opção "Sem resposta" ficam um monte de perguntas sem respostas. Mas que já foram solucionadas no próprio comentário.

Comment: Eu concordo com o uso dos comentários dessa forma, principalmente quando a pessoa não tem certeza se o que ela vai sugerir irá causar o resultado esperado... Pelo menos ao meu ver, usar os comentários para sugerir que o OP realize alguma ação e, caso o OP diga que a sugestão tenha dado resultado, seja transformado em resposta... Para mim, só é errado quando os comentários funcionam e aquele que comentou não transforma em resposta...

Comment: Ahh... a ironia :P

Comment: @Math a ironia é linda... :P

Comment: De mesma forma que existe "Este comentário é útil..." e "Sinalieze este comentário", Não poderia ter um "Este comentário resolveu o problema"? Programadores iniciantes (e às vezes experientes) se esquecem de uma aspas ou sinal ou parâmetro ou... Estou comentando este 6 anos depois da pergunta criada e 2 anos depois de última atividade, pois sou novo na comunidade...

Answer (score 41):

Alguns motivos para postar uma possível resposta como comentário:

1. A pergunta não está muito clara e é necessário tirar dúvidas com o AP, através dos comentários a pessoa acaba dando algumas sugestões que respondem a pergunta;
2. Quem respondeu não tem confiança na resposta, e resolve por em forma de comentário, já que nos comentários não há a mesma qualidade que se espera de uma resposta;
3. Quem respondeu está com pressa e não tem como postar um resposta elaborada no momento, e então deixa um comentário que pode ser uma dica ou a própria resposta em si, e não se importa que outra pessoa responda (por exemplo quem acessa através do celular);
4. Quem respondeu sabe apenas parte da solução, e prefere apenas deixar como dica para quem quiser dar uma resposta completa; ou
5. Quem respondeu achou que a pergunta será fechada, seja por ser fora de escopo, duplicada, baixa qualidade ou qualquer outro motivo, e consequentemente acha pode ser mal interpretado em dar uma resposta e taxado de caçar reputação a qualquer custo, até mesmo em detrimento da saúde da comunidade.

Cada caso é um caso, mas geralmente, quando alguém resolveu o problema do AP através dos comentários é de bom tom esperar alguns minutos para que o mesmo transforme o comentário em resposta, principalmente para o caso 1, caso a pergunta realmente seja confusa. Mas isso pode abrir oportunidades para abusos, ou seja, pessoas que rapidamente postam algo no comentário que lembram de longe uma resposta com apenas o intuito de marcar território, nesses casos, não vejo problema em publicar uma resposta oficial e ignorar o comentário, para evitar o abuso.

No seu caso, você diz estar navegando por perguntas antigas sem resposta oficiais mas com respostas nos comentários, no seu lugar eu faria o seguinte:

1. Verificaria quando foi a última vez que o usuário foi visto no site, se não faz muito tempo isso pode significar que ele costuma visitar o site com frequencia (sim, isso é subjetivo), caso ele seja ao menos relativamente ativo no site daí eu partiria para o próximo passo;
2. Notificaria o autor da resposta-comentário sugerindo-o a transformá-la em resposta mesmo;
3. Daria uma estrelinha na pergunta, para deixá-la marcada como favorita para não esquecer de voltar nela após algum tempo caso o autor da resposta-comentário não me notifique;
4. De tempos em tempos dar uma verificada nos favoritos e ver se a pessoa respondeu.

Caso concluir que o usuário que postou a resposta-comentário não vai transformá-la em resposta, então eu partiria para uma resposta mesmo. Nesse caso, temos novamente algumas opções:

- Se a resposta-comentário for muito trivial, eu escreveria uma resposta com bem mais detalhes sobre o assunto, explicando o por quê do problema acontecer, como evitar de acontecer novamente, melhor jeito de tratá-lo, etc... em minha autoria, ou seja, sem ser wiki e gerando reputação para mim caso receba votos e aceitação por ela;
- Se a resposta-comentário respondia parcialmente a pergunta, mas oferecia uma boa informação, então eu publicaria uma resposta em meu nome e incluiria um agradecimento na mesma. Um exemplo de [uma resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14414/3117) e [um comentário muito útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14403/como-obter-o-%C3%BAltimo-dia-%C3%BAtil-do-m%C3%AAs/14414#comment25354_14403). Perceba nos comentários posteriores que o @Renan disse que não podia postar uma resposta pois ele não sabe nada de Java, por isso ele deixou apenas uma dica nos comentários;
- Se a resposta-comentário for muito boa e exigiu um alto nível de conhecimento ou um baita esforço do usuário, então eu colocaria uma resposta no formato wiki e explicaria que estou apenas oficializando a resposta dada nos comentários que não pôde ser oficializada pelo respondedor.

Comment: Também não adianta sugerir que o cara transforme em resposta se for alguém que não é visto no site há tempos.

Comment: Estes três senhores disseram tudo :)

Comment: Eu já respondi e ainda respondo muitas perguntas nos comentários, mas nem faz diferença. Muitas respostas minhas sequer recebem upvotes, então, comentando ou respondendo, tanto faz, desde  atenda ao OP e que não se esteja atrás apenas de upvotes.

Comment: Olá Math! O tópico é bem antigo mas me surgiu uma pequena dúvida: quando vamos comentar, aparece tipo um _placeholder_ no campo de comentário dizendo assim: "_evite responder perguntas em comentários_". Mesmo assim é permitido "responder" mesmo nas situações que vc citou nas sua resposta? Obg!

Comment: @dvd é permitido responder, só que você não ganhará (nem perderá) reputação por isso, entretanto não tem grandes vantagens em responder pelos comentários, geralmente se faz isso quando não tem segurança da resposta ou como nos casos acima por exemplo vc está com pressa demais para dar uma resposta completa e você prefere deixar uma dica ou para o AP ou para alguém que quer dar uma resposta mais completa

Comment: Eu sei que esse topico tah meio morto ha uns anos. Eu uso muito o SOen e estive aqui durante o inicio do SOpt. Recentemente, quando retomei o habito de passear por aqui, fiquei impressionado com a quantidade de respostas em comentarios.

Comment: @LuizAngioletti aproveita pra ganhar uns pontos e oficializa essas respostas então ;)

Comment: @Math, essa eh a estrategia corrente :P

Answer (score 15):

Eu responderia por comentário, mas comentário não tem imagem.

TL;DR eu respondo por comentário quando tenho

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

A [resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2334/43) já postada pelo @math faz um ótimo diagnóstico, por isso vou colocar sugestões para tentar resolver os pontos do diagnóstico e na questão levantada na pergunta sobre atrapalhar ou não.

Antes de tudo, minhas sugestões são no sentido de incentivar um comportamento em quem é novato no SO. O pessoal mais acostumado com a plataforma é menos sensível a incentivos.

**Problemas levantados no diagnóstico**

1. **Quando o comentário tenta tirar dúvida e acaba respondendo**: Esse caso acredito não ser parte do problema. Se a intenção foi comentar perguntando sobre um aspecto que não estava na pergunta e isso acabou ajudando a achar a solução, é justo entender que não foi intencional e nesse caso incentivar a pessoa a criar uma resposta para ser marcada como solução aceita.
2. **Quando a pessoa não tem confiança na resposta**: Nesse caso acho que poderia ser incentivado a não fazer dessa forma. Eu percebo que comentários nessa linha levam para uma espécie de chat de tentativa e erro dentro dos comentários e poluí a resposta. Incentivando o autor a criar uma resposta nesses casos pode tirar o foco desse tipo de exemplo de quem chegar na perguntar procurando pela solução. Tendo a resposta fora do comentário vai reforçar a ideia de que essa é a melhor forma de responder.
3. **Quando a pessoa tem pressa ou preguiça em responder**: Esse caso é complicado porque quem está com pressa ou preguiça para criar a resposta normalmente não vai criar a resposta depois. Eu vejo que são raros os casos em que a pessoa volta e coloca a resposta. Eu entendo que a intenção é boa e quem está perguntando também pode estar com pressa e o resultado vai ser bom, mas acho que deveria ser incentivado a não fazer dessa forma. A ideia da comunidade é ajudar a pessoa que está fazendo a pergunta naquele momento e outras que podem chegar nela depois. Se a resposta está no comentário, dificulta a vida de quem vem depois.
4. **Quando a pessoa sabe parte da resposta**: Esse caso é complicado porque existe a chance da pessoa que está respondendo não ter entendido a pergunta ou que a pergunta está incompleta e ela está tentando acertar a resposta, mas acaba que o problema era diferente depois. Pode acontecer também de quem perguntou achar a resposta ali mas a pergunta estava errada e ela acaba não acertando o texto da pergunta depois. Isso me parece ruim para quem chega nessa pergunta depois. Eu mesmo (no SOen também) já cliquei em várias respostas em comentários que no final não levaram à solução. *Talvez* o melhor nesses casos, seria conter a vontade de responder e tentar comentar para que a pergunta fique bem clara e permita uma resposta completa por quem souber a solução.
5. **Quando a pergunta pode estar fora de escopo ou bloqueada**: Esse caso acho que ocorre o que está no diagnóstico. A pessoa fica com receio de ser mal interpretada. Nesse caso acho que não tem incentivo para melhorar porque a pergunta pode não seguir o ser removida, então não vejo como poderia prejudicar a comunidade.

> Isso pode atrapalhar?

**Na visão da comunidade, pode atrapalhar.**

A ideia por trás do mecanismo de Q&A do SO é permitir que várias pessoas contribuam com respostas diferentes para a mesma pergunta e assim, as outras pessoas, que teoricamente não tem tempo para elaborar uma resposta ou que verifiquem que a resposta já é suficiente para atender à quem tem a dúvida, possam demonstrar que uma resposta é boa dando pontuação positiva para ela e demonstrar que a resposta é ruim dando pontuação negativa.

Normalmente pontuação negativa também vem com um comentário para explicar porque ela é ruim. Comentários positivos também podem ser feitos por quem consegue lembrar de algum detalhe que o autor da resposta não cobriu e pode melhorar o entendimento.

O mecanismo de recompensa identifica resposta pelas respostas e não pelos comentários. Usar uma função para fazer outra distorce o funcionamento da ferramenta.

**Na visão de quem precisa de ajuda, não vai atrapalhar.**

Quem está pedindo ajuda normalmente não se importa se a resposta veio pelo comentário. Resolvendo o problema é o que importa. As pessoas que transformam comentário em resposta normalmente é mais experiente no SO e entende tanto o objetivo da recompensa como o benefício para a comunidade.

Em resumo, eu posso dizer que parar de tentar encaixar quadrado em furo redondo e ter uma visão mais sistêmica dos problemas também ajuda no nosso crescimento profissional.