# Menos comentários, mais respostas!

Tags: debate, comentários

Eu queria rapidamente lembrar que o propósito do site é dar respostas e não escrever sugestões de solução ou a própria solução nos comentários.

É bastante frequente encontrar pessoal a tentar ajudar nos comentários mas é menos frequente essas pessoas despenderem do seu esforço para responder. Eu não tenho nada contra comentários que tentem ajudar, mas apelava, para que sempre que haja conhecimento e informação suficiente na pergunta que os usuários despendessem o esforço de responder.

Há alguma coisa que pode ser feito para incentivar mais respostas e menos comentários?

Comment: Muitos comentários em uma pergunta indicam problemas ou seja está mais para ser fechada do que clara.

Comment: Perfeito para o APA e para o comentário acima, a não ser que poderia ser uma resposta :D Claro, para o meta é diferente, mas vejo muito o abuso de comentários quando deveria ser uma resposta, e geralmente indica que a pergunta está ruim. Oops, comentei em vez de responder :) Vamos ver as soluções que o pessoal vão propor.

Comment: Eu tenho feito isso com frequência. Acho que os [**5 motivos**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2334/99718) listado pelo Math, resume bem isso.

Comment: Pra mim o problema disto é causado principalmente (mas não totalmente) pela talvez falta de alguma clareza na pergunta, formular uma resposta inteira sem ter certeza do que a pergunta pede é complicado

Comment: @ValdeirPsr costumo fazer os comentários por uma mistura das razões 2, 3 e 4. Eu priorizo ajudar o AP, seja como for. E como não gosto de responder de qualquer jeito, mas de fazer uma resposta mais completa, acaba que o desejo de ajudar o AP acaba levando em comentário. Inclusivo, eu acabo comentando em perguntas que eu sei que são condenadas a serem fechadas e removidas

Comment: Tb acho que pode haver má interpretação da pergunta: pra um usuário a pergunta pode parecer pouco clara, pra outro não. Ou seja, o usuário que não entendeu direito não vai responder, e o que entendeu vai responder.

Comment: Falando nisso, acabei de fazer de novo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/294083/java-generic-type-como-parametro-do-metodo-readentity-do-jax-rs-client#comment597977_294083; sei nem se devo tentar escrever uma resposta antes do feedback, mas a ajuda foi fornecida, pelo menos alguma ajuda...

Comment: Tenho que ser o advogado do diabo aqui: Mais comentários e menos respostas. Principalmente ao tratár-se de usuários mais experientes. Já escrevi várias respostas (com muitos *upvotes*) que não resolveram o problema do OP. Eu prefiro deixar um comentário, ver se estou no caminho correto e então formular uma resposta. Mesmo que isso não seja a melhor estratégia do ponto de vista de acumular reputação. Perguntas ruins não justificam respostas ruins. Por ordem de preferência eu prefiro: Comentar em respostas -> Comentar em perguntas -> Responder

Comment: Talvez já coberta por "[Por que muitas pessoas respondem nos comentários em vez de criar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2333/por-que-muitas-pessoas-respondem-nos-coment%c3%a1rios-em-vez-de-criar-uma-resposta)"

Comment: @Bacco Nao era bem uma pergunta, era mais para ver se havia mais pessoal a responder em vez de comentar. Mas percebi que muitos preferem ter o cuidado de ter a certeza que a respsota vai efetivamente responder á pergunta.

Comment: @BrunoCosta entendo. Só achei por bem recomendar, caso não tivesse sido notada a outra postagem, fiquei meio na dúvida por serem duas abordagens (a outra como um questionamento, a sua mais como uma sugestão)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vou responder ao invés de comentar, já que a crítica do tópico é neste sentido :P.

Eu costumo comentar bastante. Hoje mesmo escrevi um comentário do tipo:

> Tente: `algum código`

Faço isto para me certificar que minha solução pode ajudar o usuário de alguma forma, podendo ser a própria resposta (na qual eu fornecerei em seguida, de acordo com o feedback do OP) ou ajudar a cercar a causa do problema.

Eu evito ao máximo fornecer uma resposta sem ter uma razoável certeza que ela solucionará o problema. Muitos irão discordar de mim e gostaria muito de saber se esta minha impressão pode ser baseada em dados, mas uma pergunta já respondida (boa ou não) **afasta novas visitas** para a pergunta e, por consequência, diminui a possibilidade de novas e melhores respostas.

Quando vou responder eu tenho em mente esta possibilidade, então tento fazer com bastante cuidado para o bem da própria pergunta e do autor da mesma.

Comment: `mas uma pergunta já respondida (boa ou não) afasta novas visitas para a pergunta` - de fato, isso ocorre realmente, eu ja respondi algumas perguntas que ja tinham respostas e ja vi outros casos, e quanto maior o intervalo entre as respostas, parece que menos atencao ela receba. Claro que depende de quem responda tambem, se for um usuario ja reconhecido por boas respostas daquela tag(ex universal: Maniero :p ), é provavel que receba um pouco mais de atenção do que algum usuário ainda "engatinhando" no site.

Answer (score 9):

*Vou dar um depoimento pessoal de quem só tem 5 meses de StackOverflow.*

**Vou começar com uma observação do ponto de vista do usuário e do dispositivo móvel.**

Muitos usuários navegam pelo site por dispositivos móveis, que muitas vezes não facilitam na hora de testar algo antes de responder. Logo quando só temos o celular disponível nas mãos não nos resta muito mais do que fazer comentários, pois seria "**arriscado**" perder pontos e responder sem testar ou pesquisar mais profundamente.

Ao meu ver o maior fator para tantos *comments* e poucas respostas não é só a preguiça e sim o medo de perder pontos com os **DownVotes** ou responder e não ganhar nada. ***Acredito que uma campanha boa seria para as pessoas votarem mais. Na minha humilde opinião o "prazer da recompensa" poderia ajudar muito nesse ponto.

Como eu respondo muito em CSS o bom é que mesmo uma pergunta simples pode ter mais de uma resposta, então eu não me acanho em responder. Outro dia mesmo eu respondi uma pergunta que já tinha 19 respostas!

Infelizmente novos usuários, mesmo que com alguma reputação, se sentem inseguros em dar respostas, pois para eles os "pontos de reputação" ainda são valiosos e difíceis de se conseguir, então preferem comentar antes de responder sem ter certeza absolutíssima. Acredito isso se deve ao medo da "*retalhação*" dos **DownVotes**, assim preferem comentar.

Eu mesmo, muitas vezes pergunto ao Autor da Pergunta se uma resposta com determinada técnica seria válida para ele. Se ele sinalizar que sim eu respondo e ainda digo *"Como solicitado Pelo Autor da Pergunta nos comentários segue uma resposta na forma x"*

[]'s

Comment: A razão: *"(...) pois seria "arriscado" perder pontos (...)"*, deverá ser: *"(...) pois seria "arriscado" dar uma resposta errada (...)"*.

Comment: Lá isso é verdade, no começo eu evitava responder pois eu não tinha a certeza se enterpretava a pergunta corretamente e tinha medo de ter downvotes :s