# Responder com "chute" e depois remover a resposta caso não atenda

Tags: debate, respostas

Me deparei com uma situação curiosa [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/302016/8063) em que eu não tinha visto ainda nos meus 6~7 meses de atividade no SOpt e que me gerou dúvidas em relação à boas práticas.

O AP acusa um erro de sintaxe em seu código:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input...

Fiz o teste e indentei o código e não foi verificado nenhum erro de sintaxe. O erro em questão se dá quando uma `{` não foi fechada, o que não é o caso. Vejam que tudo abre e fecha corretamente:

```
fetch(
   url,{
      mode: 'no-cors',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json'}
   }
)
.then(
   function(response){
      response.json()
      .then(
         function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
      )
   }
)
.catch(
   function(error){
      console.log(error);
   }
);
```

O caso é que um usuário postou uma resposta solicitando o AP a "tentar" utilizar a solução dele (pedir pra "tentar" ao meu ver já não é uma forma concreta de resolver o problema, ou seja, um *chute*) e ignorando o erro mencionado na pergunta, abordando outra coisa alheia ao problema apontado. E acrescentou ainda que "se caso a resposta dele não resolvesse" ele iria remover a resposta.

Muito bem, diante desse cenário, surgiu-me essa dúvida em relação á atitude do AR:

É legal agir dessa forma fazendo um *chute* e se não der certo, simplesmente remover a resposta?

Até porque caso ele receba downvotes ou o AP disser que não resolveu, basta ele remover a resposta que os pontos negativos serão estornados e ficará o "dito pelo não dito". Se for assim, é muito fácil, nem precisa mais tentar esclarecer nos comentários as dúvidas em relação à pergunta: basta postar qualquer resposta e se não *der certo*, simplesmente remover(!).

Qual a visão do site e da comunidade me relação a isso? Caso o AR receba downvotes e remova a resposta e os 2 pontos de reputação perdidos sejam devolvidos, fica alguma coisa ainda negativa em sua conta caso ele tenha recebido downvotes?

Comment: Se a resposta tem algum fundamento, eu até acho válido. As vezes a pergunta não é tão clara, carecendo de edição, e os comentários não são suficientes para transparecer uma ideia que você tem sobre a solução. Se tem fundamento, não vejo porque não o fazer. Sempre haverá conteúdo que pode ser absorvido pela comunidade. No caso citado, não vejo razão para; a resposta foi dada bem aleatoriamente, sem esforço algum de confirmar as informações e, inclusive, com erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Mas neste caso a resposta não tem nenhum fundamento. Aborda outra coisa completamente diferente. É como se eu perguntasse:" _Não consigo abrir a porta do meu carro, a chave não roda_" e recebesse como resposta "_Tente trocar o pneu pra ver se resolve_"

Comment: Ainda que não tenha a certeza, eu estou convencido que o sistema monitoriza a quantidade de postagens removidas, especialmente com pontuação negativa, e começa a limitar a quantidade de coisas que pode fazer, naturalmente dependerá de vários fatores, como a reputação que ele tem, etc. Mas corrijam-me se o que eu disse não for verdade.

Comment: Vou apontar meu comentário em [outra pergunta não relacionada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6998/menos-coment%c3%a1rios-mais-respostas#comment27010_6998): A resposta para isso, ao meu ver, são mais comentários e menos respostas. Não vejo problema em chutar algo ou mesmo dar uma sugestão nos comentários; mas eu não faria o mesmo em uma resposta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> É legal agir dessa forma fazendo um chute e se não der certo, simplesmente remover a resposta?

Depende do sentido de "legal" aí. Não é proibido nem ilícito, afinal a plataforma permite esse comportamento.

Mas legal de ser de boas, não é. Infelizmente, devido às políticas do SO, eu não posso dizer aqui o que esse tipo de comportamento realmente é, mas começa com a letra 'e'.

> Até porque caso ele receba downvotes ou o AP disser que não resolveu, basta ele remover a resposta que os pontos negativos serão estornados e ficará o "dito pelo não dito".

Esse comortamento não é esperado (e nem comum, felizmente) entre usuários experientes. Já usuários inexperientes podem se surpreender ao terem seus direitos de publicação suspensos por alguns dias. É que publicação removida pode até reverter pontuação, mas continua contando para a política de qualidade que bane quem faz muitas publicações com pontuação negativa.

> Qual a visão do site e da comunidade me relação a isso?

Visto que esse é o comportamento padrão do SO há anos, acredito que é algo esperado pela equipe de gestão e a de desenvolvimento - caso contrário essa funcionalidade já teria sido modificada.

Quanto à comunidade - não posso falar por todos nós, mas acredito que o fato do SO ser "gamificado" atrai vários tipos diferentes de desenvolvedores. A maioria quer contribuir para o conhecimento acumulado, afinal cada publicação útil ajuda a todos os desenvolvedores de forma geral. Mas tem sempre aqueles tipos que acham que a genitália cresce na proporção de seu score em um ou outro jogo online, e fazem do SO o jogo da vez. Só podemos ter paciência... Não existe sistema de verificação de idade online que esses usuários não conseguiriam burlar.

Comment: rs.. tentei adivinhar o que começa com  a letra "e" e não consegui rs... acho que meu vocabulário de palavrões é bem enxuto... dá uma dica aí pra eu saber o que é? rs

Comment: @dvd faz parte da anatomia masculina e garda as jóias da família.

Comment: Ahhh tahhh rsrs.. vlw!