# O quão "errado" é responder uma pergunta antiga usando uma resposta de outro usuário que foi dada apenas na área de comentário da pergunta?

Tags: debate, respostas

Já vi em inúmeras ocasiões aqui no SOpt um usuário descobrir a resposta de uma pergunta usando somente a conversa da área de comentários. **Sempre** que vejo esta situação, eu recomendo ao usuário que deu a resposta via comentário a formalizá-la como uma resposta na própria pergunta, para que a pergunte não fique sem resposta e ele consiga colher os louros do seu esforço ao ajudar o colega.

Contudo, nem sempre as pessoas fazem isto: por não fazerem questão de formular a resposta, de não voltarem mais ao site, etc. Como consequência a pergunta fica sem resposta, sendo que ela existe desapercebida e pouco detalhada nos comentários.

Nestes casos, seria errado formular uma resposta e fornecê-la na pergunta com base no que o outro usuário respondeu na área de comentários?

Comment: Possiveis motivos do porque as pessoas comentam ao invés de responder: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2333/3635, sobre se é certo ou errado em perguntas antigas vejo como o mesmo para novas, se ninguém responder, então responda, vc esta colaborando com a comunidade ... Agora o problema é responder a uma pergnuta com problemas, que no minimo deveria estar fechada, ou até mesmo já tem resposta em outra pergunta, o que a tornaria duplicata. ps: assim que tiver um tempo transformo meu comentario em resposta (incluindo detalhes) :)

Comment: Complementando esse link que o @GuilhermeNascimento mencionou.... o maior problema hoje em dia que eu vejo é quando as pessoas respondem uma pergunta que poderia ser esclarecida em forma de comentário e que deveria estar fechada (erros de sintaxe, problemas ou dúvidas repetidas, etc)

Comment: Só comentando rapidamente: se continuar fazendo [boníssimas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/317466/64969), a contribuição ao site vai ser incomensurável

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, obrigado! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Se você pode postar uma resposta sua, porque entende do assunto e pode acrescentar algo então dê sua resposta.

Se só irá reproduzir o comentário para que a pergunta tenha uma resposta então coloque-a como Community Wiki, porque não é sua resposta, você está postando em nome da comunidade.

Answer (score 6):

O site recomenda *não responder perguntas nos comentários*, conforme print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas é bem comum ver usuários postando respostas nos comentários. Mas isso é bem compreensível porque muitas vezes o usuário não tem certeza se aquilo irá resolver a pergunta. Se resolver e tiver a ciência do AP, acho que o autor do comentário tem a oportunidade e preferência de postar uma resposta formal. Se outro usuário se aproveitar disso e se antecipar formulando uma resposta igual, com certeza é oportunismo. Cabe ao AP marcar a resposta como aceita ou não ou esperar que o autor do comentário o faça.

Agora, se o autor do comentário, depois de um tempo, não postar uma resposta, acho válido qualquer um fazê-lo. Ora, muitas vezes a solução postada no comentário é a mesma que outro usuário imaginou. E se o autor do comentário não quis postar uma resposta, não vejo problema de outro fazer.

Acho que tudo é questão de bom senso e honestidade. Se o autor do comentário "abandonou" a pergunta, poste a resposta, mesmo que seja a mesma solução. Acho que o mais importante é não deixar a pergunta sem resposta.

Comment: Vale salientar que é elegante fazer a menção: "conforme comentário do Fulano...", ou então "baseado no que Sicrano escreveu..." Isso deixa claro que sua intenção como autor não é roubar a resposta, mas realmente produzir conhecimento

Comment: Isso é o correto mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

Não faz muito tempo(13/07/2018) respondi a uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/312332/2541) que se enquadra na situação que refere.

Era esta a situação:

- Um comentário indicava ao AP uma abordagem possível para a resposta à pergunta.
- O AP colocou uma resposta com uma implementação que estava "errada"(após a minha resposta e comentários editou).
- Passados 8 dias a situação mantinha-se.

Em situações idênticas a essa não vejo problema em que outro possa responder.
Considero até que é desejável, desde que siga o que o é dito na resposta do [Maniero.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7194/2541)

Answer (score 2):

Deixar a pergunta sem resposta acho ruim, quem pesquisa pode achar que não "teve solução". A sua ação é correta e incentiva quem ajudou, mesmo que com comentários, a escrever a resposta e receber a pontuação.

Agora se o usuário não respondeu depois de um tempo, é perfeitamente aceitável que quem fez a pergunta poste a solução como resposta, mencionando o usuário quem ajudou nos comentários.

Se não for o usuário quem fez a pergunta, mas outro que apenas leu o conteúdo, parece oportunismo, mas se ele formular uma boa resposta, como um exemplo funcional, links para referência, me parece que também é uma boa solução, melhor que deixar a pergunta sem repostas.

Comment: Acho que essa visão esta indo muito para o lado *"suporte técnico"*, quando devemos pensar em atender mais do que o AP em questão, pois nem tudo que resolve o problema (supondo que o ap mesmo tenha resolvido) é correto de fato. Tem muito de "eu ajudei", "fulano ajudou", esta faltando "citar fontes", "tentar tornar as respostas mais uteis a futuros visitantes". Eu entendo a boa fé de vcs em tentar ajudar, mas realmente o suporte técnico (que não sou totalmente contra) esta demais e criar respostas uteis a todos esta de menos no site, não estou dizendo que vc fez isso, mas muitos tem feito assim

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, como eu comentei, se há uma pergunta que o usuário acabou respondendo através de comentários, resolvel o problema mas o mesmo usuário não optou por postar uma resposta, por que não escrever como resposta?  A ideia é responder a pergunta *"O quão errado é"*, e acredito que não seja errado, pelo contrário, mas entendo o que você quer dizer com *"suporte técnico"*