# Respostas em comentários

Tags: debate, respostas, comentários

Tenho notado que muitas pessoas estão comentado e dando a resposta nos comentários. Isto não é bom para a comunidade.

Claro que há casos que a pergunta não está clara (embora ela deveria ser fechada) e aí é só uma tentativa, mas há muito caso que é a resposta. Muitas vezes inibe outra pessoa responder porque no fundo já foi respondido, e aí a pergunta fica sem uma resposta.

Se tem uma reposta para a pergunta, responda! Comentários não foram criados para dar a resposta ali.

Não tenha vergonha. Se der algum problema, se comprometa a apagar depois, pode até escrever como citação que o fará se for necessário pra se proteger. Se tiver bom senso, só será uma resposta quando responde mesmo.

Comment: Cuidado que apagar respostas pode levar a bloqueio para responder. Não pode ser assim de animo leve que se responde...

Comment: Parece-me duplicata de [Por que muitas pessoas respondem nos comentários em vez de criar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2333/5878)

Comment: @JorgeB. isto só ocorre com novatos :) O problema é apagar uma alta porcentagem. E é o que eu falei, se vai responder, que seja uma resposta, se for feito assim dificilmente haverá a remoção.

Comment: @Maniero foi só para deixar claro isso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não acho que seja exatamente dup, mas se acharem podem fechar. Lá debate realmente o assunto, aqui estou só fazendo um aviso para que as pessoas tomem cuidado com isto. Fiz de forma simples e objetiva para que as pessoas leiam. Ainda pensa igual?

Comment: Estou com fome, então meu julgamento pode estar afetado, mas de início sim. Lá já possui bastante conteúdo sobre o assunto e, ao meu ver, esse aviso poderia ser posto lá como forma de resposta justificando os malefícios que isso traz à comunidade.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss agora passei ter medo de você :D Não quero conversa antes do almoço... E eu não acho que funcionaria bem, mas é só uma opinião.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Por que muitas pessoas respondem nos comentários em vez de criar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2333/por-que-muitas-pessoas-respondem-nos-coment%c3%a1rios-em-vez-de-criar-uma-resposta)

Comment: @Maniero, é algo que tenho visto com certa frequência também. Particularmente não me sinto confortável em responder a pergunta que na prática já foi respondida, pois pode soar como "plágio". Como agir nessas situações?

Comment: @H.Lima totalmente. Aí leia o *link* que estão considerando dup.

Comment: Normalmente quando eu respondo em um comentário ou em um chat eu "formalizo" como uma resposta, mas na intenção de deixar documentado para futuras buscas.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo aí tá beleza.

Comment: As vezes eu respondo nos comments, mas só qnd estou no smartphone, depois eu volto e vejo se há uma resposta boa, se tiver eu nem respondo ou so complemento, caso contrário eu respondo.

Comment: Ontem mesmo me encontrei em uma situação em que o indivíduo não havia colocar o erro na pergunta. Sugeri que fosse colocado o stacktrace para que pudesse ser analisado. Quando o cidadão o fez, percebi que a classe que ele colocou na pergunta não era a mesma que disparava o erro. Ao invés de pedir que colocasse o código da classe certa, falei qual era a classe, a linha e o problema que havia ocorrido. Peço desculpas se me enquadro na situação deste post, mas foi o que eu imaginei ser o mais conveniente na hora. Aliás, o erro era causado por uma simples tentativa de conversão para um numero real

Comment: A propósito, sou meio que novato. Acesso o SOPT tem alguns anos, mas não tem muito tempo que estou tentando me tornar ativo na comunidade. Já fiz uma resposta que recebeu alguns votos negativos de uma pergunta que estava fora do escopo do site. A resposta solucionava a pergunta. Imagino que este é o receio de muitos novatos ao responderem nos comentários.

Comment: Relacionada: "O quão “errado” é responder uma pergunta antiga usando uma resposta de outro usuário que foi dada apenas na área de comentário" https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7189/o-quão-errado-é-responder-uma-pergunta-antiga-usando-uma-resposta-de-outro-usu

Comment: Acredito que toda a tentativa de responder em comentários significa falta de segurança para postar uma resposta (medo de levar vários -1*) ou algum tipo de dúvida que não ficou clara na pergunta. _*Infelizmente tem muita gente sacana que vota -1 inescrupulosamente, por isso o medo de colocar uma resposta com dúvidas._

Comment: Eu tenho notado isso, e se talvez como existe a opção de sinalizar resposta "não é uma resposta", para comentários onde são resposta haver uma opção de "é uma resposta" assim com a moderação apenas transformando o comentário em resposta ou então avisando para que o autor transforme a mesma, assim que o comentário for aceito pelo autor da pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Eu acho que deveria ser feito dessa forma:

Quando a resposta é correta e não tem outro tipo de solução:

Notificar o usuário que respondeu para responder no lugar correto.

Quando a reposta é correta mas falta algo:

Responder explicando a teoria e o que falta na resposta do comentário.

Quando a resposta é correta mas existe outras possíveis soluções:
Responder com as possíveis soluções e citar a solução do comentário.

[Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365694/como-fazer-borda-da-imagem-abaixo)